# suppress footnote-mark configuration in Tex4HT

Tags: tex4ht

I tried to get the below output for footnote in through TeX4HT

```
<p class="indent">Some Text<fn id="sample_fn_001" symbol="1"><p class="noindent">language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond</p></fn> some text text</p>
```

I just tried to re-configure  the `footnote` and `footnote-mark`

```
\newbox\footnotebox

\Configure{footnote-mark}{\Configure{textsuperscript}{}{}}{}



\Configure{footnotetext}{\global\setbox\footnotebox=\vtop\bgroup\NoFonts%
                         \ifvoid\footnotebox\else\unvbox\footnotebox\fi%
                         \IgnorePar\HCode{<fn id="\jobname_fn_00\thefootnote" symbol="\FNnum">}\par\ShowPar\IgnoreIndent%
                         \Configure{textsuperscript}{}{}%
                        }%
                        {\Configure{textsuperscript}{\HCode{<sup>}\bgroup}{\egroup\HCode{</sup>}}}%
                        {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\HCode{</fn>}\egroup\box\footnotebox}
```

i am getting the below output

```
<p class="noindent">Some Text1<a id="x1-1001f1"></a>    </p><fn id="sample_fn_001" symbol="1">   1language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond</fn>                     
    some text text
```

in the footnote mark footnote number is printed in the footnote mark place and in the footnote? how to suppress the footnote number and Link ID `<a id="x1-2f1"></a>`

para also closing in the wrong place `</p>` before the `<fn>`

please suggest how to configure this to get the expected output

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Sample TeX4HT}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{A Head}\label{sec1}

Some Text\footnote{language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond} some text text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

I've found a fix for the spurious `<a>` command. The next link destination for a cross-reference can be disabled using the `\SkipRefstepAnchor` command. The following configuration patches the `\footnote` command with that. Description of rest of the code follows in the original answer bellow the configuration file.

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\makeatletter

% remove the footnote number in text
\Configure{footnotemark}{\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup}

% the <fnlabel> element is used to enclose the <a> element inserted by the referencing mechanism
% it will be then removed using Lua post-processing


\Configure{footnotetext}{%
\SaveEndP% don't print </p> in the next \EndP
\HCode{<fn id="\jobname_fn_00\thefootnote" symbol="\FNnum">}%
\IgnorePar% ignore next paragraph
\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup% remove the footnote number from footnote text
}%
{\egroup\par\IgnoreIndent\ShowPar}% start the paragraph in footnote
{\EndP% insert the closing </p>
\HCode{</fn>}\RecallEndP}% insert </p> in the next \EndP

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\def\footnote{\SkipRefstepAnchor\oldfootnote}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

---

Original answer:

Your requested structure is invalid HTML, because `<p>` element cannot contain any block level element, including `<p>` itself. But if it doesn't matter to you, here is a solution:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\makeatletter

% remove the footnote number in text
\Configure{footnotemark}{\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup\HCode{<fnlabel>}}

% the <fnlabel> element is used to enclose the <a> element inserted by the referencing mechanism
% it will be then removed using Lua post-processing


\Configure{footnotetext}{%
\HCode{</fnlabel>}%
\SaveEndP% don't print </p> in the next \EndP
\HCode{<fn id="\jobname_fn_00\thefootnote" symbol="\FNnum">}%
\IgnorePar% ignore next paragraph
\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup% remove the footnote number from footnote text
}%
{\egroup\par\IgnoreIndent\ShowPar}% start the paragraph in footnote
{\EndP% insert the closing </p>
\HCode{</fn>}\RecallEndP}% insert </p> in the next \EndP

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `footnotemark` configuration discards the footnote number inserted in the text. It uses a trick where we save the content into a temporary box, which is then discarded. The same trick is used also in the `footnotetext` configuration, to remove the footnote mark in the footnote itself.

The `<a>` element before footnote is inserted by the referencing mechanism and is quite hard to remove from the TeX side. This is the reason why it is enclosed in the `<fnlabel>` element. The result at this stage is following:

```xml
<!--l. 10--><p class="noindent" >Some Text<fnlabel><a 
 id="x1-1001f1"></a></fnlabel><fn id="sample_fn_001" symbol="1">
<!--l. 10--><p class="noindent" ><span 
class="cmr-8">language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond</span></p></fn>
some text text
</p>
```

The `<fnlabel>` can be removed using a `make4ht` DOM filter. Save the following as `mybuild.mk4`:

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local process = domfilter {
  function(dom)
    for _, el in ipairs(dom:query_selector("fnlabel")) do
      el:remove_node()
    end
    return dom
  end
}


Make:match("html$", process)
```

It can be compiled using

```
make4ht -e mybuild.mk4 -c config.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the final result:

```xml
<!-- l. 10 --><p class='noindent'>Some Text<fn id='sample_fn_001' symbol='1'>
<!-- l. 10 --><p class='noindent'><span class='cmr-8'>language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond</span></p></fn>
some text text
</p>
```